# Using simplesamlphp 1.10 with cakePHP 2.3 not working

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, saml, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to implement the SimpleSAMLphp authentication tool in cakePHP.
I wrote a `SamlAuthenticate` component in `app\Controller\Component\Auth` which looks like this:

```
class SamlAuthenticate extends Component {

    [...]

    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
            $source = null;
            $as = null;
            if ($this->Session->check('Saml.source')) {
                    $source = $this->Session->read('Saml.source');
            }

            if ($source) {
                    require_once($this->settings['path'] . DS . 'lib' . DS . '_autoload.php');
                    $as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple($source);
                    if(!$as->isAuthenticated()) {
                            $as->login();
                    } else {                               
                            return $as->getAttributes();
                    }
            }

            return false;
    }
}
```

But I'm always getting an loop between the identity provider and my cake application.

I was wondering, if my server is the problem or I did something wrong with the configuration of the identity provider, so I wrote a simple test script and it worked without a problem:

```
require_once('/../simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php');
$as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple('facebook');

$as->requireAuth();
echo $as->isAuthenticated();
```

So, something in cakePHP breaks the authentication process. The SimpleSAMLAuthToken is set correctly (I can see that through the SimpleSAMLphp admin panel), but `$as->isAuthenticated()` always returns false.

I also tried https://github.com/bvidulich/CakePHP-simpleSAMLphp-Plugin with the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you are in a session conflict.

Take a look on the [LostState](http://code.google.com/p/simplesamlphp/wiki/LostState) info of the simpleSAMLphp documentation.

A fast workaround to see if that is your problem:

Configure the simplesamlphp to save the session on memcache. You will need to install a memcache server, the memcache php driver (remember to restart your apache after install ir) and then edit the config/config.php file of simpleSAMLphp and set

```
'store.type' => 'memcache',
```

Check that the simpleSAMLphp can write a session using the cookie extension of firefox. (Take a look on the session/cookie params of the config/config.php file.

Comment: Indeed it was the a session conflict. CakePHP isn't using the session name configured in php.ini, it uses `CAKEPHP` instead. 
That's why the sessions never matched. Thx for the hint.

Comment: +1 for the link, and memcache is certainly fine to use as a persistent store, although if you are already using something else for application state (e.g. a database) then you don't need to install memcache as well